# Android lottie animation lags

Tags: android, android-animation, lottie

I'm developing an app for both iOS and Android. the splash screen has a JSON animation. In iOS the animation works perfectly, but in Android the same animation running with lags. have anyone experienced it?

notes:
the animation doesn't have any image resources.

I'm receiving some error logs, but they seem to be not related because I already tried other animation which runs without lags and it shows the same errors.

These are the errors:

```
W/LOTTIE: Lottie doesn't support layer effects. If you are using them for  fills, strokes, trim paths etc. then try adding them directly as contents  in your shape.
Found: [Radial Shadow]
W/LOTTIE: Animation contains merge paths. Merge paths are only supported on KitKat+ and must be manually enabled by calling enableMergePathsForKitKatAndAbove().
```

Comment: Hey @Ofek Regev I stumbled upon this same problem too. When you rendered your animation composition from AE, you probably used AE Effects/Features like "layer effects" which aren't currently supported by Lottie android SDK. You need to modify your composition and replace those layer effects with shape layers importing them directly from something like Illustrator.

Comment: Back in the days when we solved the problem the designer told me he used some masks in AE which probably caused this problem. Thanks for the answer anyway.

Comment: I totally ignored this warning.

Answer (score 1):

As your warning message says, try setting `enableMergePathsForKitKatAndAbove()`.

Example , in xml -

```
<com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
    ...
    ...
    ...
    app:lottie_enableMergePathsForKitKatAndAbove="true"/>
```

OR, in Java -

```
lottieAnimationView.enableMergePathsForKitKatAndAbove(true);
```

Comment: Also, you can try scaling down the animation to reduce the lag. What was the original res you created these animation json in?